# Optimize Column Transpose in SQL with Daily Data Across Multiple Years

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pivot, query-optimization

I would like to transpose the Date values from a column into rows and have the relevant data populate underneath them based on respective Firm names. But I need a contiguous, daily time-series across multiple years even if there are blanks (so column 1 = Firm name, column 2 is day N, column 3 is N+1, column 4 is N+2 etc).

I've been using the below query, but when I replicate the "SUM(CASE WHEN..." roughly 4000 times to get contiguous daily dates since 2013 (via copy/pasting from Excel) and expand the "P.FirmName in..." to roughly 1000 entries, the query runs slower than a slug.

Is there anything I can do to optimize this type of query up after expanding it to contain ~4000 "SUM(CASE WHEN..." dates and ~1000 "P.FirmName in..." values?

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT P.FirmName,
SUM(CASE WHEN [DATE] = '2023-11-30' THEN [TOTAL] END) as '2023-11-30'
SUM(CASE WHEN [DATE] = '2023-12-01' THEN [TOTAL] END) as '2023-12-01'
SUM(CASE WHEN [DATE] = '2023-12-02' THEN [TOTAL] END) as '2023-12-02'
SUM(CASE WHEN [DATE] = '2023-12-03' THEN [TOTAL] END) as '2023-12-03'
FROM [Total].[Database] S
Left Join [Product].[Database] P ON S.Product = P.Product
Where FirmLocation not in (-1,-2,-3) and P.FirmName in (Apple, Banana, Cherry)
Group by P.FirmName
```

The query ran but -- and I can't stress this enough -- at an incredibly slow pace when expanded to include all the Dates and FirmNames.

---

Per request to provide a minimal reproducible example, I updated the above query and included screenshots of the relevant data in each table alongside the desired results:

[Total Database Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr50q.png)

[Product Database Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaUh7.png)

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezfeH.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results. Text descriptions of data just don't cut it.

Comment: Are you aware that there's a hard limit of 4096 columns allowed in a `SELECT` statement? This sounds like bringing a presentation layer problem into the database: why isn't your application/reporting layer doing this date-based pivot from multiple rows of data output from `SELECT p.FirmName, [Date], SUM([Total]) AS [Total] ... GROUP BY P.FirmName, [Date]`?

Comment: SQL Server boasts a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax. But it's hard to use. @AlwaysLearning is right: this is a job for an application programming language.

Comment: Hi Dale -- I updated original post and provided screenshots of a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning -- Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but if I group by [Date] it will return millions of rows because any given FirmName can have thousands of rows in a given day, and my desired output is trying to consolidate this into one row per firm for a respective date

Comment: Hi O. Jones-- So you're thinking I'd have to use something outside of SQL?

Comment: Disregarding the fact that reading thousands of columns is kinda ridiculous, are you sure the problem is actually the pivot part? You wrote something about firm, do you actual mean you have a really large `IN ('firm1', 'firm2', 'firm3'... 'firm1000')` somewhere in the query? SQL Server doesn't like large INs. Also, are your firm names indexed? You should probably put all the firm names into a temporary table with an index on the name and join on that table.

Comment: Another thing, your query is just plain wrong. Adding `Where P.FirmName in (Apple, Banana, Cherry)` means you have turned your LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN, because NULLs in P.FirmName will lead to rows being filtered out. Also, posting screenshots of data is discouraged here, because you can't copypaste it to text

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIVOT`, dynamic query, and `STUFF` (to create a comma-separated string from `DATE`s):

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

SELECT FirmName, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL, CAST([DATE] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as Date 
INTO #temp
FROM [Total].[Database] S
Left Join [Product].[Database] P ON S.Product = P.Product
Where FirmLocation not in (-1,-2,-3) and P.FirmName in (Apple, Banana, Cherry)
GROUP BY FirmName, Date;
  
DECLARE @dates NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(
(
  SELECT ',[' + Date + ']'
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM #temp
  )t
  FOR XML PATH (''))
, 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT FirmName, ' + @dates + '
FROM  
(
  SELECT [Date],FirmName, TOTAL 
  FROM #temp
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  SUM(TOTAL)  
  FOR [Date] IN (' + @dates + ')  
) AS PivotTable'

EXEC(@query)
```

Here is [an executable query on AdventureWorks database](https://dbfiddle.uk/lbBNFyN-)